Excel PivotTable - Format 4th or 5th Subheading
I'm wondering if there's a way to format the 4th, 5th, etc... Row Subheading when modifying the PivotTable styling in Excel or through VBA? I can see the PivotTable Elements only allow styling up the the 3rd Row Subheading.

My Sheet:

I've even tried to format column "B" through VBA; trying to unbold. However, that didn't work as I assume the PivotTables styling takes precedent?
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").Font.Bold = False

I've also looked at unselecting the "Row Headers" option (to remove bolding on Column "B") under Design Tab > PivotTable Style Options but that removes the bolding from my "Name", "Dep Name", "Cat Name" RowHeadings and my Column "B" rows.


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xltablestyleelementtype - There is no xlRowSubheading4 element of XlTableStyleElementType. Your best bet here would be choosing a style with no formatting, then format it with VBA.  As you said in your post, the PivotTable formatting will trump any standard cell formatting.

Ah okay, didn't know for sure if it did. Maybe formatting through VBA over a blank style is the only way to go. Thanks for the insight!
